# flowtype errors in base AwesomeProject

Tags: react-native, flowtype

I recently wanted to reset a react-native project to most recent version, and so I initialised the seed project - "AwesomeProject"...  The problem is that it comes with 19 flowtype errors "out of the box"

```
node_modules/react-native/Libraries/CustomComponents/NavigationExperimental/NavigationCardStackStyleInterpolator.js
lines:91,94,97,104,107,137,142,148

node_modules/react-native/Libraries/CustomComponents/NavigationExperimental/NavigationHeaderStyleInterpolator.js
lines:57,68,74,87,94

node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Experimental/WindowedListView.js
lines:629, 629, 665,665

node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/Image.ios.js
line:272
```

I am reluctant to make changes to these files as it may create knock on effects.  Does anyone have a work around?

Answer (score 0):

In general, whenever you want flow to ignore a file, you can just specify that file under the `[ignore]` section of your .flowconfig.

That said, I just `react-native init`'d a project, using react-native-cli 1.0.0 and react-native 0.29.1, and ran a flow server on the root of my project, and didn't get any errors.

Comment: What version of flow are you running?

I did a brew upgrade of flow (from v0.23) to v0.28.0, before creating the new project and the .flowconfig says [version] ^0.27.0.  So it could be a difference in the flow version itself.

Interestingly brew can't find the previous flow version (can't find it for some reason), so I an unable to confirm.  Is there a way you know of installing previous version of flow to check?

Comment: Huh.  I was using flow 0.27.  I just upgraded Flow to 0.29, and got all the errors.  So I did a `brew switch flow 0.27.0`, and it was all working again.  I guess RN doesn't support 0.28+ yet.

Comment: Yeh - its a waiting game now for update. And thanks for confirming.  Lucky for you that you have 0.27.0; other versions are not available to install - not sure why....